# Is it okay to write "gale force" without the hyphen?

Tags: punctuation, hyphens

> Northern New South Wales is bracing for more flooding today. Heavy
>   rain and **gale force** winds are expected to hit the region later this
>   morning. [(ABC News)](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2013-02-22/abc-news/4533540)

ABC’s news script has no hyphen between gale and force. Is it okay or does it need to be changed?

Comment: It is a desirable courtesy to the reader, but it is not obligatory.

Comment: The trend these days seems to be leaving out hyphens whenever you think you can get away with it. I like them, though. My personal rule is: does it make it easier to read? If so, I use the hyphen.

Comment: @snailplane I blame the omnipresence of the keyboard. In writing, nothing is easier than a hyphen; in typing you must truncate the natural rhythm of your fingers, which insert a space mechanically, and reach up an extra row for the hyphen.

Comment: I wouldn't normally bother with it. I can't see anyone would need the hyphen to aid legibility (it's such a common collocation you often see it written as a single word). Why include it if you don't need to?

Comment: There are plenty examples of [both](https://www.google.com/search?q=gale+force+winds&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22gale+force+winds%22&hl=en&safe=off&tbm=bks&ei=pMsmUaeIA5CA2QXSn4CIAw&start=20&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42768644,d.b2I&fp=9b35d69dfec2d049&biw=1186&bih=846) in the literature, and the [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gale+force+winds%2Cgale-force+winds&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) difference is small enough to be negligible. Seems okay as is; no need to batten down the hatches for that missing hyphen.

Comment: @J.R. Consistency has much to be said for it.

Comment: @tchrist: I agree. If ABC leaves the hyphen out once, they should leave the hyphen omitted for subsequent occurences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to most style guides, yes, you need hyphens in compound adjectives.

(Note that this only applies to adjectives that come before the word they modify: in *she was old fashioned*, it is not necessary, because it comes after; in *an old-fashioned woman*, it is.)

The general rule is to use hyphens only where they are necessary to prevent ambiguity or where they save readers the embarrassment of having to reread a passage. In practice, not all compound adjectives are problematic without hyphens; however, in this case uniformity trumps other concerns. If compound adjectives are always hyphenated, you have something to rely on as a reader. This is an advantage in itself. Secondly, it is easier for writers if they don't have to think about whether or not the compound is still readable without a hyphen.

I have more or less paraphrased Fowler's perspective here, as in *Fowler's Modern English Usage*; but I believe most style guides reason along similar lines.